# Symfony2, FOSUserBundle - fetching user data on each request

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

After I successfully log in and check my application I also look at number of queries run against database (mysql one). And there is always a query fetching user data. How can I force FOSUserBundle to store user object in session instead fetching it all the time from database?

**edit**

My `security.yml` have this setting (among others about firewall)

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could change the user provider for a custom one which would do what you need. It has a `refreshUser()` method, which I suspect is responsible for these requests (I guess your current user provider must be this one https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/UserManager.php, which extends this one https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php , which does implement UserProviderInterface (and another one)).

Comment: I added part of my `security.yml`

Comment: ok then I was wrong. I edited my answer, have a look at the user manager you're using, have a look at the userproviderinterface too :  it has a loadUserByUsername() method too, which could also be responsible for the requests.